# How to add Owl-Carousel-2 completeness percent(%) status bar(not progressBar)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

First of all this is not about "progressBar", I need a completeness percent(%) status bar for owlCarousel-2, if there is any confusion in my question and description then please check the images below.

I have just created a pen, please check the link - https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/NmpGmV

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [testyourprojects.biz](https://www.testyourprojects.biz/html/slimimag/html/assets/images/img-2.png))</sub>

I just have complete with "Total Item count" and "Current item count", but can't implement the status(%) bar like the images I have posted. Please check my code below.

```
$(function(){
var owl = $('.ivySlide');
$('.ivySlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:false,
  onInitialized:counter,
  onTranslated:counter
});
function counter(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var items = event.item.count;
  var item = event.item.index + 1;
  var sldtxt = $('.active .ivySlideTxt').html();
  $('#counter').html(item+" / "+items)
}
});
```

Comment: Please check this: https://codepen.io/gjk/pen/BpyYoj/  Is this fulfill your requirement?

Comment: _“but can't implement the status(%) bar like the images I have posted”_ - show us what you tried at least then. What is the actual problem (considering that the “math” is pretty trivial)?

Comment: please check the pen - https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/NmpGmV

Comment: Finally I have got the solution please check the pen - https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/NmpGmV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have got the solutions for this, please check the code below and also the pen.

```
$(function(){
$('.ivySlide').owlCarousel({
  smartSpeed: 500,
  items: 1,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  dots:false,
  onInitialized:counter,
  onTranslated:counter
});
function counter(event) {
  var element = event.target;
  var items = event.item.count;
  var item = event.item.index + 1;
  var sldtxt = $('.active .ivySlideTxt').html();
  var sldWidth = 100;
  var sldPercent = sldWidth * item / items;
  $('#counter').html(item+" / "+items)
  $('.slTxt').html(sldtxt);
  $('.slideState span').css("width", sldPercent + "%");
  $('.slideState span').html(sldPercent + "%")
}
});
```

You can check my solution here https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/NmpGmV